# non-ajax call not working in moved DOM

Tags: jsf, dom, primefaces

due to some other reasons moved some part of DOM into other place by using JQuery, in this moved DOM i have one non-ajax button its not working now.

below is the moving code

```
var duplicateOverCount = 1;
var duplicateOverPandata;
var duplicateOverRecdata;
function duplicateScrOvrPanFix() {
    while (duplicateOverCount < 2) {
        duplicateOverPandata = $('.duplicatSrcOverLaySty')[0];
        duplicateOverRecdata = $('.duplicateSrcRecordsSty')[0];
        $('.duplicatSrcOverLaySty').remove();
        $('.duplicateSrcRecordsSty').remove();
        duplicateOverCount++;
        }
        $(duplicateOverPandata).appendTo('.frozencolDatatabe');
        $(duplicateOverRecdata).prependTo('.frozencolDatatabe');
}
```

Below is non-ajax call button, it need download file. i'm using primefaces 6

```
<p:commandButton
                    value="exportExcel"
                    ajax="false" action="#{xyzMBean.abc}" onclick="bypassLocking();">
                    <p:fileDownload
                        value="#{reportMBean.streamedContent}" />
                </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Then why did you move it? And where to? Just moving it does not mean it stops working... It depends on where it is moved to etc... what is still around it (form wise) etc...

Comment: is it being moved in the same form (ViewState), or is it being duplicated ?